# Array into html table using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have 2 tables in a DB that I am joining with a PDO executes and I have it outputting in one form of table but I need it in a another format. Do I need some form of dynamic pivot?

The 2 tables are like this:

[image: Tables in database]

I am looking to get the following table from it:

[image]

The current query I am using to collate the data is:

```
$sql3 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT b.title, a.nameFROM poll_summary a INNER JOIN poll_answers b ON a.answers_id = b.id WHERE a.poll_id = ? ORDER BY title');
$sql3->execute([$_GET['id']]);
$testing = $sql3->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is a sample array of what it gives:

```
Array ( [Knight ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dave ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Simon ) ) [Lieutenant ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tom ) ) )
```

I can get the table headers from the title column using:

```
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <?php
            foreach($testing as $key => $val):
            ?>
                <th><?php echo $key;?></th>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>        


    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I can't figure out how to get the name values into the correct columns.
I tried using this code but just can't get it to work how I want it to.

```
foreach($testing as $key => $val) {
    $arrlength = count($val);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    //echo $key;

    echo $key;
    echo $val[$x]['name']; 

    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
Knight Dave Knight Simon Lieutenant Tom
```

Comment: You should `bindParam` before you `execute` the query.

Comment: @LeonKunštek Why? This is PDO, the prepare/execute code as shown is perfectly valid.

Comment: What would you bindParam to? This page will be used to various different polls / inputs / outputs so it will be different values every time. Would binding answer the question I asked?

Comment: OP, why would "Simon" have the title "Knight"? Why would "Tom" have the title "Lieutenant"?

Comment: @SimonT you would `bindParam` to this `a.poll_id = ?` which you did in `execute`, also my comment was more of a tip on improving the code.

Comment: It's a poll vote on certain titles given to something. The names are the people who voted for said title so we can see who voted what.

Comment: But you're still giving it a value of `[$_GET['id']]` in execute, so my **suggestion** would be to move `[$_GET['id']]` to `bindParam` and then `execute` normally.

Comment: @LeonKunštek There is no reason to bind the variables separately. That will not change anything, it just makes the code longer for no reason.

Comment: @SimonT I see now, it's 2 separate tables.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I know, as I said before it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already having this structure in $testing:

```
Array ( [Knight ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dave ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Simon ) ) [Lieutenant ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tom ) ) )
```

Make the table

```
<?php
    // Just to keep same variable
    $output = $testing;
?>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<?php
    // We need to know wich $title has more names
    $max = 0;
    foreach($output as $title => $names) {
       if(count($names) > $max) {
          $max = count($names);
       }
?>
                <th><?php echo $title;?></th>
<?php } // end foreach ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    // Loop for creating table rows
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
?>
    <tr>
<?php
        // Loop for creating table cells
        foreach($output as $title => $names) {
?>
        <td><?php
             // Echo only if name exists
             if(isset($names[$i]['name'])) {
                echo $names[$i]['name'];
             }
        ?></td>
<?php
        } // end foreach
?>
    </tr>
<?php
    } // end for
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: print of $output has no data = Array ( [] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) )

Comment: In your question you've posted **Array ( [Knight ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dave ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Simon ) ) [Lieutenant ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tom ) ) )** and it's the same that $output that I've suggested, then go directly to make the table, just update variable names.

Comment: There's nothing to update though as the variables are all the same....yet the print / vardump of $output is blank

Comment: Actually I think I can see where you have gone wrong, ['title'] is in the array, it is the key.

Comment: I've updated my answer using what you get in that output.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot Triby. Also seems cleaner than original answer. Apologies in how I said "gone wrong"